# PHPExcel - Write/append in chunks

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using the PHPExcel framework to try to write out a very large excel document from a mysql query.

Everything works fine until I hit the 5000 row mark (or there about's) where the page gets flagged with the error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate yyy bytes) in zzz on line aaa
```

I know this is documented, and I have adjusted the memory allocation on the server but even so I am still hitting the ceiling. I have also tried to turn off formatting, but in reality I will need it on.

So is there a way to write in small chunks, or append to the excel document so I don't exhaust the memory allocation? I am thinking along the lines of the page writing say 1000 lines, then redirect to itself and process the next 1000 using a GET to keep track. For example:

`index.php?p=0`

then redirect to

`index.php?p=1000`,

But I can't find a way to append to an existing document without opening up the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of writing in chunks, although a common mistake is for people to load their mysql data to an array, then loop through the array setting the Excel cell data. It's more memory efficient to set the cell data as you loop through the mySQL query resultset.

If you need to keep memory usage to a minimum, what cell caching method are you using? Cell caching is slower, but can save significant amounts of memory.

Comment: Cache! I didn't even set that, good call. Quick follow up question, for a large document with lots of writes, which of the cache methods would you pick? I just tried `cache_to_discISAM` which worked for up to 10,000 rows of about 6 columns, but bugged-out at 60,000. Don't get me wrong 10,000 is awesome, and will be ample - but I like to stress test my apps. EDIT - I don't care about speed in this case

Comment: EDIT 2 - I am running on an apache/linux server (so win cache is out)

Comment: All of the current production release cache methods retain at least a cell map "in memory", so (for example) DiskISAM holds the size and location of the cell reference in the file "in memory" as does phpTemp. The most memory efficient caching mechanisms in the production code are memcache, APC and WinCache, where the map is just a simple "cell exists" boolean. The latest SVN code (in pre-release testing) adds SQLite as a caching option, which is even more memory efficient (there is no "in memory" map at all, everything is inside SQLite)

Comment: Caching is always a trade off between memory and speed: the lower the memory, the slower the execution speed. There's a table in http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/234150?ProjectName=phpexcel that shows the relative speeds/memory usage of the different caching methods.